# Altium Designer route hint missing

Tags: altium

I'm using Altium 17. Recently I just imported an Eagle project then I generated the component library with `Design-> make integrated library`. The components and their footprints created successfully and I added them to my project. After I completed the schematic, I generated the PCB but I got into a very strange problem, when I move these imported components the route hint appears and when I place the component all route pins to that component disappear. This problem happened only for imported components from Eagle project. When I close my project and reopen it all the pin names from component disappear and when I move them the hint no longer exist at all. I checked the schematic and PCB library and couldn't found any problem. I tried to create a new schematic symbol and copied the pcb, but didn't work.
Here are some pictures.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the PCB: View -> Connections -> All

Also, make sure that the color for these hints is set to something visible in the Layer View options (the button on the very lower left with the color of the current layer)

Comment: Thanks, It didn't work for me. I think it is because of some bugs by importing from Eagle but somehow I fixed it with first create a library in Eagle and then import the file as a library.